# EF Code First - How to add foreign key property when using InverseProperty?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

I have the code first model defined below.

There are two relationships between Project and TeamMember:

1. many-to-many - TeamMember can work on many projects. Project can have many TeamMembers.
2. one-to-many - Project always has one TeamMember as Manager.

   ```
   public class Project
   {
       public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

       [InverseProperty("ManagedProjects"), Required]
       public virtual TeamMember Manager { get; set; } // 2

       public virtual List<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; } // 1
   }

   public class TeamMember
   {
       public Guid TeamMemberId { get; set; }

       public virtual List<Project> Projects { get; set; } // 1

       [InverseProperty("Manager")]
       public virtual List<Project> ManagedProjects { get; set; } // 2
   }
   ```

This model generates the Project table definition shown below.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Project] (
  [ProjectId]            UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  [Manager_TeamMemberId] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Project] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ProjectId] ASC),
  CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Project_dbo.TeamMember_Manager_TeamMemberId] FOREIGN KEY
    ([Manager_TeamMemberId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TeamMember] ([TeamMemberId]));
```

I need to extend Project with a foreign key property for Manager but can not figure out to do this.

```
public Guid ManagerId { get; set; } // 2
[InverseProperty("ManagedProjects")]
public virtual TeamMember Manager { get; set; } // 2
```

The above code does not work as it just generates a ManagerId field in the Project table. I Have tried different combinations of ForeignKey og InverseProperty without any luck.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Next code should create join table for many-to-many and 'Project' table will have foreign key on this table.

```
public class Project
{
    public Guid ProjectId { get; set; }

    public virtual TeamMember Manager { get; set; } // 2

    [InverseProperty("Projects")]
    public virtual List<TeamMember> TeamMembers { get; set; } // 1
}

public class TeamMember
{
    public Guid TeamMemberId { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("TeamMembers")]
    public virtual List<Project> Projects { get; set; } // 1

    [InverseProperty("Manager")]
    public virtual List<Project> ManagedProjects { get; set; } // 2
}
```

I think that impossible have many-to-many relationship without join table.

Comment: My model does already generate the join table for the many-to-many relation (1). The generated tables actually looks as expected. The problem is, that I want a foreign key property for the one-to-many relation (2). Whatever I do I can not get it to map to the Manager_TeamMemberId field. Have a look at Relationship Convention at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj679962.aspx.